# How does Devouring Arrow work?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

While trying to [figure out the math for Hungering Arrow](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71340/what-rune-makes-hungering-arrow-do-the-most-damage-on-average), we discovered that we don't know how the Devouring Arrow rune works:

> **Hungering Arrow:** Fire a magically imbued arrow that seeks out targets for 115% weapon damage and has a 35% chance to pierce through targets.
>
> **Devouring Arrow:** Each consecutive pierce increases the damage of the arrow by 70%.

Does this mean that each hit gets another 70% weapon damage added (so a second hit would be 115 + 70 = 185%)? Or that the total damage is increased by 70% (so a second hit would be 115% * 1.70 = 195%)? Or something else? This doesn't make a big difference on the first hit but the cumulative effect could be large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested it and it is most likely that it is the 185% so it just adds 70% (115+70)

to the data:

normal hits without pierce made up 50 dmg that are 115%.
so 100% wpn dmg was about 43.47 i'll take 44.
70% from 44 are 30.8.
so one pierce would make 80 dmg,
2 would make about 110 dmg 
and 3 would make about 140 dmg

I shurely collected more data. one Pierce made about 80 dmg
2 pierces made about 110-120 dmg
and 3 pierces made about 140-155 dmg

As you see it is the 185% weapon dmg.

All data was made with a 16.5 dps 2 handed crossbow 14-16 dmg without any other gear on a mallet lord in act4 hell with my DH lvl 60. Additionaly i had no dmg buff passives active (had hot pursuit, brooding and tactical advantage)

Comment: By my math, if it worked the other way, 2 pierces should be 145 damage and 3 pierces should be 245 damage. These numbers are sufficiently different from what you saw that it looks like you're right!

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to think that it increases your total damage because of the wording.
"Devouring Arrow: Each consecutive pierce increases the damage of the arrow by 70%."
Total damage of the arrow is 115% weapon damage and then your second iteration the 195.5% damage would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

From the wording, I'd disagree with Chris Porter.  It says it increases the damage of the arrow, not the damage done.  The damage of the arrow is 115% weapon damage, +70% = 185%.

That's taking the wording very literally though, it'd be interesting if you could accurately compile some data on it.  Due to the range of damage of a "hit" you'd have to take quite a few samples compile the data and compile a mean average of the second hits damage.  Too time consuming for a monk like me :P

But yah, I'd bet you dollars to doughnuts it's only 185% damage...